# cancel foreground notification without stopping service as the service displays multiple notifications

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

i have download service that i display multiple notifications by it
i make the service always foreground to make it not killed
each notification i display has custom remoteview that has cancel button

I want to make download service acts like what Google chrome download service does which has pause and cancel button in each notification

i display each notification by

```
        startForeground(1, notification1);
        startForeground(2, notification2);
        startForeground(3, notification3);
```

i want for example when i click on cancel button in notification2
i cancel this notification i.e remove it from notification bar
without stopping the service
as the service is used to display the other notifications 1,3

```
            notificationmanager.cancel(2)
```

doesn't work as it is displayed by startforeground

and also i want also  to stop the service only when i click on cancel button on any notification if there is no other notifications in the notification bar

Comment: Have you had a solution already? I'm facing the same case as yours.